# how to create the image dynamically in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to create the image dynamically based on the points i get from table

if point =1

my  image must be displayed once,

if point=2

imgae has to be display twice.... in that way

Comment: Please clarify your question, ans we'll try to answer it.  Are you trying to build an image that has multiple images in it, or place an image link on the page multiple times?

Comment: A _small_ (don't paste the whole project in) distilled example showing the problem might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the answer

get the count values in a datatable and based on the value use

```
for(int i=0;i<value;i++)
{
string strimage="";
strimage="<img src=''.../>";

}

div.innerhtml=strimage;
```